# I have question abour this ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

import csv

with open('haitham.csv.txt','r') as csv_file: #file :

```
#list = file.readlines()
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

for line in csv_reader:
print(line)

Comment: Ask your question. And use proper markdown for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change file name `haitham.csv.txt` to `haitham.csv`